# What does it mean in C : #define ABC(a,b) {#a, a, b}

Tags: c, ansi-c

What does it mean in C :  #define ABC(a,b) {#a, a, b} ?

I understand that ABC is a Macro with parameters (a,b).

But what does it mean {#a, a, b} and especially what does mean "#a" in such case?

Answer (score 2):

This is used to do stringification. From [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.1/cpp_3.html#SEC32).

> Sometimes you may want to convert a macro argument into a string
>   constant. Parameters are not replaced inside string constants, but you
>   can use the `#` preprocessing operator instead. When a macro parameter
>   is used with a leading `#`, the preprocessor replaces it with the
>   **literal text of the actual argument, converted to a string constant**.
>   Unlike normal parameter replacement, the argument is not
>   macro-expanded first. This is called stringification.

There is an example in the manual itself which clears the idea.

```
#define WARN_IF(EXP) \
do { if (EXP) \
        fprintf (stderr, "Warning: " #EXP "\n"); } \
while (0)
WARN_IF (x == 0);
 (expanded to)==> do { if (x == 0)
           fprintf (stderr, "Warning: " "x == 0" "\n"); } while (0);
```